# 弾く/弾ける in 何か楽器をひけますか

Tags: kanji, readings

> 何か楽器をひけますか

appeared in ISBN-13: 978-4828867588 on page 102.

Question 1: Is the kanji form of the verb 弾く【ひく】*to play (a stringed or keyboard instrument)*?

Question 2: If the answer to Q1 is yes, why is it conjugated ひけます?

> a) Because it is "Non-past, polite: 弾きます"? (Jim Breen)
> b) Because it is "Potential, polite: 弾けます"? (Jim Breen)

Question 3: Does one read the first kanji as 何か【なにか】or as 何か【なんか】?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **`Is the kanji form of the verb 弾くto play (a stringed or keyboard instrument)?`**

Yes. 弾{ひ}く is the correct kanji for playing keyboards, and stringed instruments.

And you should say

> 「何{なに}か楽器{がっき}を演奏{えんそう}出来{でき}ますか?」

for any musical instrument.

However probably not correct usage though, I often use

「何{なに}か楽器{がっき}をひけますか?」 "Do you play some instruments?"

for any musical instruments like even drums, flutes, etc.

2. **`If the answer to Q1 is yes, why is it conjugated ひけます?`**

> a) 「何{なに}か楽器{がっき}を弾きます?」

It implies "Do you usually play any musical instruments?" or "Do you want to play/try any musical instruments? (Probably at music shop)"

> b) 「何{なに}か楽器{がっき}を弾けます?」

It implies "Can you usually play any musical instruments?"  As you quote, it is talking about the ability to play instruments.

3. **`Does one read the first kanji as 何{なに}か or as 何{なん}か?`**

「何{なん}か」is a colloquial form of 「何{なに}か.」
So you can shorten the sentence to **「何{なん}か楽器{がっき}弾く?」** to form the heavy metal band.